# Linear programming: choosing entering variable

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, operations-research

maximize 101 + 122 +123

subject to

1 + 22 + 23 + 4= 20

21 + 2 + 23+5= 20

21 + 22 + 3 +6= 20

1, … , 6 ≥ 0

This is my first step for simplex tableau

x1 x2    x3  x4  x5  x6

0   4   1   2   2   1   0   0   20  20

x5 0    5   2   1   2   0   1   0   20  10

0   6   2   2   1   0   0   1   20  10

10  12  12  0   0   0   0

***Now which variable should be entering variable?***

What confuses me is since we have two 12 on cj-zj column, I suppose we should choose x2 or x3 as entering variable, but simplex calculator proceeds with x1 as entering variable.

Comment: I would choose $x_2$ or $x_3$ as entering variable as well. But there exist many other rules for choosing the entering variable. B.t.w the column with the objective function has to be multiplied by (-1).

Comment: @callculus You mean the last row? I think some books use $c_j - z_j$ instead of $z_j - c_j$

Comment: It looks like $x_2$ or $x_3$. You can try using [this](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html)